# blueprints.forEach(function (b) { ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

While running `merng` command I am getting this error :

```
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mern-cli\lib\commands\generate.js:43
blueprints.forEach(function (b) {
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ashwanipanwar\AppData\Roaming    \npm\node_modules\mern-cli\lib\commands\generate.js:43:16)
at Command.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Command.outputHelp (C:\Users\ashwanipanwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mern-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:1142:8)
at Command.help (C:\Users\ashwanipanwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mern-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:1152:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ashwanipanwar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mern-cli\lib\commands\generate.js:49:25)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

what is the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

I found , error is coming because `merng` needs `arguments`. Like `merng module <moduleName>` and this will create a module.